# unit test seems to work but doesn't insert data

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I'm trying to write all the unit test for my DAO layer in objective c for a project I'm working on, but when I run them, everything seems ok while debugging it. For example, I can find the database and execute the query. I know these because I get SQLITE_OK every time I do an operation. Based on this everything looks ok and when I check the database i expect to see de data I'm trying to insert in my test.

What I'm trying to do is test the methods that insert a "Rol" in my database.

The code looks like these:

UnitTest

```
#import "RolTests.h"

@implementation RolTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    // Set-up code here.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.

    [super tearDown];
}

-(void)testInsertarRol
{
    Rol *rol = [[Rol alloc]init];
    rol.nombre = @"CEO";
    rol.descripcion = @"Master of the universe";

    DAORol *dao = [[DAORol alloc]init];
    BOOL insertRealizado = [dao insertarRol:rol];
    STAssertTrue(insertRealizado, nil);
}

-(void) obtenerRol{}

-(void) obtenerRoles{}

-(void)modificarRol{}

-(void)testEliminarRol
{
    Rol *rol = [[Rol alloc]init];
    rol.identifier = 3;

    DAORol *dao = [[DAORol alloc]init];
    BOOL rolEliminado = [dao eliminarRol:rol];
    STAssertTrue(rolEliminado, nil);
}

@end
```

DAORol

```
#import "DAORol.h"

@implementation DAORol

-(BOOL)insertarRol:(Rol *) rol
{
    BOOL respuesta;

    NSString *ubicacionDB = [self obtenerRutaBD];

    int b = sqlite3_open_v2([ubicacionDB UTF8String], &bd,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

    if(!(b == SQLITE_OK)){
    NSLog(@"No se puede conectar con la BD. Error %i ", b);
}


const char *sentenciaSQL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Rol     (nombre,descripcion) values ('%@', '%@')", rol.nombre, rol.descripcion] UTF8String];

   sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

   int i = sqlite3_prepare_v2(bd, sentenciaSQL, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
   if (i == SQLITE_OK) {
    respuesta = YES;
   }
   if(i != 0){
    NSLog(@"Problema al preparar el statement. Error %i ", i);
    respuesta = NO;
}

    return respuesta;
}

@end
```

DAOBase

```
#import "DAOBase.h"

@implementation DAOBase

- (NSString *) obtenerRutaBD{

  NSString *dirDocs;
  NSArray *rutas;
  NSString *rutaBD;

  rutas = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  YES);

  dirDocs = [rutas objectAtIndex:0];

  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  rutaBD = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dirDocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"totem.sqlite"]];

  if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:rutaBD] == NO){
    [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"totem.sqlite"] toPath:rutaBD error:NULL];
  }

  return rutaBD;
  }

@end
```

EDIT:

I change my unit test to look like these

```
-(void)testInsertarRol
{
    Rol *rol = [[Rol alloc]init];
    rol.nombre = @"CEO";
    rol.descripcion = @"Master of the universe";

    DAORol *dao = [[DAORol alloc]init];
    BOOL insertRealizado = [dao insertarRol:rol];

    NSMutableArray *roles =  [dao obtenerRoles];

    for (Rol *rol in roles)
    {
        NSLog(rol.nombre);
    }

    STAssertTrue(insertRealizado, nil);
}
```

If you loop roles you would expect to see "CEO" but...you don't...so the data was not inserted in the data base

What I expect after running these test is having a row in my Rol table whit the values "CEO" and "Master of the universe"...but the data doesn't get inserted.

I Have no idea what is wrong so any pointer would be great.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you just need to add a single line after sqlite3_prepare_v2(bd, sentenciaSQL, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL); in all statements that need to commit changes to the database (Insert, update & delete).

Just add sqlite3_step(sqlStatement); and you are done!

You can even do something like

if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
   SUCCESS
 }
else{
   ERROR
}

Answer (score 0):

Once your test complete the rol that you created for the test will be deleted. Setup is called before each test and teardown is called after. If you are checking after the teardown you won't find the inserted values. Test are not run in order either. Each test should be independent of all others. You can use multiple asserts in each however.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm checking the data base right just before **BOOL insertRealizado = [dao insertarRol:rol];**. I can debug the test so I know that after that line i can go and check the db...any other ideas?